# tomcat hbase jar inclusion

Tags: tomcat, maven, jersey, hbase

I am trying to setup a simple hbase webapp using tomcat. To my knowledge I understand that i need to include the hbase jar, and hadoop jar in order to use hbase along with the zoopkeeper jar.

The problem is when I include the hbase jar in my maven pom, it downloads all sorts od transitive dependent jars that I dont want (e.g. jetty, servlet-api etc) because hbase itself has its own in built jetty web app that is used for monitoring. I believe this conflicts with tomcat packaging and start up that results in my having the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

root cause

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:69)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.create(ServletContainer.java:391)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.create(ServletContainer.java:306)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:607)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 logs.
```

When I comment out the hbase jar from my pom (all the dependent jars for hbase vanish too as expected), and tomcat deploys fine and I can access my rest/spring servlet.

I have tried to use exclusions to excluse hbase direct dependencies with the following:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.90.3-cdh3u1 </version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                    <!-- <version>1.4</version> -->
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
                    <!-- <version>6.1.14</version> -->
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
                    <artifactId>thrift</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But to no avail I still have the problem.

So has does anyone have an exiting pom where they have including hbase and hadoop and somehow got tomcat to work perhaps using jersey too?

I know the above is not detailed I will add more details. I will paste the maven full pom.

thanks so much

Comment: If anyone has an example tomcat hbase setup using maven please can you advise how to include the hbase jars in the tomcat web-inf lib appropriately.

Comment: How does the resulting war look like? (i.e. what libraries are included in it?) What version of Jersey are you using? As far as I can tell, HBase also depends on Jersey. Maybe with HBase you are pulling another version of Jersey and that's what's causing the issues?

Comment: hi Martin, I am using tomcat 6. Jersey-server-1.8.jar, jersey-core-1.8.jar, jersey-spring-1.8.jar. I didnt realise HBase also depends on Jersey, perhaps I need to exclude this too? I will give this a shot. thanks for your comments. I'll be back with an update.

Comment: hi Martin that worked fine. I excluded the Jersey hbase dependency and it resolved it. thanks so much. amak. 

    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   </exclusion>

Comment: OK, posted it as an answer, so that others don't think this is still unanswered. Can you please accept the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HBase depends on Jersey as well, so you need to make sure you don't end up with two different versions of Jersey in your app.